# Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, jitsi-meet

I tried to build jitsi meet based on react-native but it stucks in bundleReleaseJsAnd assets and then throw this error :

```
Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem in my
Putting

```
project.ext.react = [
     entryFile: "index.js"
]
```

In App build.gradle

Comment: And what about hermes?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so to clarify Sumakh's answer -- this happened to me because I had a build error in my app's JavaScript code. Ergo the build step invoking node to build the runtime bundle threw an exception. To find the script error, there are a couple of options:

- I ran eslint against my JS sources, which identified the error, then fixed it, and was off to the races.
- After the fact, though, I realized that IntellJ (where I was editing the JS code) had been warning me about the syntax error (showing the red squiggly underline on the file in question)
- If you have a pre-existing working runtime, you could also try running the current state of the JS code in your simulator, and it should throw an exception showing you where the bad code is.

Answer (score 1):

Just kill node process and repeat the build process.

Comment: how do you do that ?

Comment: first identify process number after `kill -9 <process-number>`

Comment: and run `ps -ax | grep node` to check node process-number

Answer (score 0):

Kill too many processes.

Restart your computer and try again:

```bash
yarn start
```

Answer (score -4):

This is because of code style for jshint errors in your HTML files. 
Use IDE which supports HTML files, and shows errors in HTML if any. Sometimes, errors in the HTML will still work in browser, but build will fail.